# Calculating 3d angle from two angle projections

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d, angle, projection

[image: Angle C and it's projections]

I am wondering if there's a straight-forward way to find a 3d angle from it's 2d components, similar to how a vector norm can be found from it's cartesian components.

For illustration, suppose in the figure angles A and B are known. Is it possible from this information to find the angle C?

Comment: The angle C (between the blue and green lines) can be found from the position of C. Information at A and B is irrelevant. If you restate your problem to find B, then simply raising A and C will change those angles but not B's. you need lengths and if you need lengths you know the position of C.

Comment: The 3D equivalent of the plane angle is known as solid angle.

Comment: Maybe I misused the term '3d angle'. What I mean is I want to find an angle in one plane from it's projected angles onto two orthogonal planes, as shown in the drawing.

Comment: I think you might find the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207665/projecting-an-angle-from-one-plane-to-another-plane